# Add-PnPJavaScriptLink sequence after sp.js

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell

```
Add-PnPJavaScriptLink -Name $scriptName -Url $scriptLink -Sequence 0 -Scope Site
```

I want to ensure that the script is loaded after sp.js

Answer (score 0):

[Add-PnPJavaScriptLink](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/add-pnpjavascriptlink?view=sharepoint-ps) is used to add a link to a JavaScript file to a web or site collection.

Scripts are loaded in the order encountered in the page.

To ensure that script is loaded after sp.js, use `SP.SOD.executeFunc` method or `SP.SOD.ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded` method.

Comment: this doesnt work in sharepoint online